# if condition in javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare the values and return the message.But the message returned always. How can i do it?

Javascript:

```js
function Calculation() {
  var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>");
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
    var txtcurrentrcvamount = $("input[id*=txtrcvQuantity]")

    var cell = $("#gvGoodReceived").find("tr:eq(0)").find("td:eq(2)").text();
  }
  if (txtcurrentrcvamount > cell) {
    alert("Receive quantity must be less or equal PO quantity");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `txtcurrentrcvamount` appears to be a jQuery object, not a string or number. What is the purpose of `for` loop?

Comment: how can i get   the value and compare with cell

Comment: See the Answer to your Question, get the `.value` of the element, or using jQuery, `.val()`. Is the expected result for `cell` to be the same value at each iteration?

Comment: NO cell value will be different in each iteration.

Comment: take the `txtcurrentrcvamount` out from for loop. Everything will be okay.

Comment: Your current code uses only a single element. Are you trying to pass `i` to `.eq()`? `.find("tr:eq(" + i + ")")` ?

Comment: Showing same Output. var txtcurrentrcvamount = $("input[id*=txtrcvQuantity]").val()
              var cell = $("#gvGoodReceived").find("tr:eq(" + i + ")").find("td:eq(2)").text();

Comment: `.val()` returns the first element of the collection returned by `jQuery()` which means `txtcurrentrcvamount` will also be defined as the same value at each iteration of the `for` loop

Comment: How can i manage it?

Comment: Without a `for` loop `var res = $.map($("input[id*=txtrcvQuantity]"), function(el, index) { return +el.value > +$("#gvGoodReceived").find("tr:eq(" 
+index+ ")").find("td:eq(2)").text() }); if (res.some(function(bool) {

return bool })) { return false }`

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the [value](https://api.jquery.com/val/) of your input:

```
var txtcurrentrcvamount = $("input[id*=txtrcvQuantity]").val()
//                                                      ^^^^^^
```

Since you're comparing numbers, and `val()` and `text()` return strings, you should convert your values to numbers before doing the comparison:

```
if (Number(txtcurrentrcvamount) > Number(cell))
```

Do note that `Number(someStringThatIsNotANumber)` will return [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Comment: The `>` operator coerces string to number,  yes?

Comment: Not all the time. Only if one of the operands is a number. If both are strings it performs lexicographical comparison i.e. `'b' > 'a' === true`.

Comment: Can you post an example or link to a Question/Answer where comparing numbers as strings using `>` or `<` operator does not return the expected result?

Comment: No, but that's not the point. The point was to not give false positives like `'b' > 'a'`. I guess we can do more explicit type checks but I didn't want to overwhelm the OP since it is obvious this is a beginner's question. It just seemed this was a simple yet helpful answer. I don't mind making a change if you have a suggestion.

Comment: Was curious about that portion of your Answer relating to comparing numbers as strings. Your mention of lexicographic comparison furthered that initial curiosity. There are other issues with OP's code. `var cell = $("#gvGoodReceived").find("tr:eq(0)").find("td:eq(2)").text();` would be the same value for each iteration, though OP states that  a different element defined as `cell` for each iteration is expected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393756/if-condition-in-javascript-function-not-working/48393779?noredirect=1#comment83775264_48393756.

Comment: @guest271314 Actually, a simple example would be `'10' > '9' === false`

Answer (score 1):

Because your scope of a variable **`(txtcurrentrcvamount)`** is limited in between for loop, That's why this not working outside the loop scope.

for more detail, you can view this post...[scope of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

For using this variable in **if condition** you have initialized it before the **for loop**...

**EDIT:**
Try this may this help you either. I think there some other finding to suppose you have two rows in your grid then which row value you want to check because **this always return last row value**... and if there a number value for both of the variable assignment `txtcurrentrcvamount ,cell` then it should be work perfectly.

```
function Calculation() {
  var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>");
  var txtcurrentrcvamount ;
  var cell;
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
    txtcurrentrcvamount = $("input[id*=txtrcvQuantity]").val();
    cell = $("#gvGoodReceived").find("tr:eq(0)").find("td:eq(2)").text();

  }
  if (Number(txtcurrentrcvamount) > Number(cell)) {
    alert("Receive quantity must be less or equal PO quantity");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: i declared (txtcurrentrcvamount)  variable out of the loop but it's not working in case of my condition.